# How to change the View Mode of DocumentViewer

Tags: wpf, xaml, documentviewer

How can I change the View Mode of `DocumentViewer`?, I want the page to be full width since the beginning.
If I use `documentViewer.FitToWidth()` it does stretch but not completely.
If I use ctrl+2 it stretches completely and thats what I want to achieve programmatically or using xaml if possible.

Thanks

Comment: I've not used this control, but I'm guessing you've already tried `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` ?

Comment: @Mashton it stretches the control not the inner data inside

Comment: Oh ok. How about `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "stretches completely"? Looking at the code in Reflector, `FitToWidth()` just calls the handler of `FitToWidthCommand` (bound to Ctrl+2).

Comment: @Dusan I found the problem. I used `FitToWidth()` too early (right after `documentViewer.Docuemnt = document`, I changed it - now I call it after the documentViewer loaded and it works fine.. I guess it was my fault - I dont understand why it stretches it almost completely when I call it right afther I load document but w/e as long as it works.

Comment: @Ron So does it mean you've solved your own problem?

Comment: @lll Yes. I cannot delete the question because of the bounty

Comment: @Ron if you have solved your own problem just post your solution as an answer and the bounty will just expire in 4 day...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem.

I used `FitToWidth()` too early (right after `documentViewer.Docuemnt = document`), I changed it - now I call it after the `documentViewer` loaded and it works fine.

I guess it was my fault - I dont understand why it stretches it almost completely when I call it right after I load document but w/e as long as it works.